# Prospective study and ascertainment of the exposure during the follow-up period

Tags: modeling, literature-research, experimental-optimization

I'm reading several prospective studies published in top journals where a baseline modifiable exposure was associated with a final outcome.
Just as an example might be [this study](http://doi.org/10.1093/eurheartj/ehy836).

The Authors aimed to evaluate whether oral hygiene behaviour can alleviate cardiovascular risk. For what I understand, the **exposure persistency** (oral hygiene behaviour) was not controlled during the study period, because any repeated assessment was performed during the follow-up.
Basically, they associated the final outcome (10yr later) to the baseline exposure.

1. Is that methodologically correct?
2. In a prospective cohort study, is there any **need** to control the exposure during the study period?

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Unfortunately this question is not within the scope of operations research, as it asks about study design and clinical trial methodology in medical statistics. However, your question would be welcome in [Medical Sciences SE](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/).